# Custom validator to compare

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

For an exercise I have to compare if 2 textboxes contain the same text with a custom validator (doing the same thing as a comparevalidator does)
BUT I cant use a compare validator for this. I have to use the custom validator for this.

It has to compare TextBox1 and TextBox2, if these don't contain the same value ( text) it have to give the error message: not the same value!

How can I solve this?

This is what I have so far:

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Not the same value !" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" />
```

And This is what I tried to do in code-behind:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (TextBox2.ToString() != TextBox3.ToString())
    {
        Label1.Text = "Not the same values";
        // don't exactly know what to do in here in order to put it in the error message
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (TextBox2.ToString() != TextBox3.ToString())` should be the following
`if (TextBox2.Text != TextBox3.Text)`
[C# MSDN how to use TextBox Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397491(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (TextBox2.Text != TextBox3.Text)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Not the same values";
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: have you compiled that code and run it..? I bet you will find that it will not check the Text of either.. where is the `.Text` property in your comparison..? `TextBox2.ToString()` will `yield` the string representation of the Object itself..

Comment: Thanks methodman, i was copying his code so he could see the args.IsValid.  I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Discussion .its about your Question and it has a solution

[Check this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1560273.aspx?Customvalidator%20over%202%20textboxes)

Updated:

Try this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Not the same value !" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>




protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (TextBox2.Text == TextBox3.Text)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;

        }
        else
        {

            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still dont have the solution.

Comment: It still doesn't check if textbox 2 or 3 are the same

Comment: @Vince Do you have any button on your Page?